# Login failed for user ''. error

Tags: vb.net, database-connection

I know that this is a duplicate post but I couldn't find my solution on that topics. I want to connect my sql file in debug folder but I got error that Login failed for user ''.

```
    Dim connectionString As String = String.Format("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename={0}\Word.mdf;Integrated Security=False;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True", My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath)

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM test"
    Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    Dim dataadapter As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection)
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    connection.Open()
    dataadapter.Fill(ds, "test_table")
    connection.Close()
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
    DataGridView1.DataMember = "test_table"
    MakePivot()
    connection.Close()
    DataGridView2.ClearSelection()

End Sub
```

Could you tell me my mistake please?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dim ds As New DataSet()
 Using connection As New SqlConnection(String.Format("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename={0}\Word.mdf;Integrated Security=true;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True", My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath))                   
       connection.Open()
       Using command As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM test", connection)
             command.CommandTimeout = 0
             Using da As New SqlDataAdapter(command)
                   da.Fill(ds)
             End Using
       End Using
 End Using

 DataGridView1.DataSource = ds   
 MakePivot()
 DataGridView2.ClearSelection()
```

Try this code, need to set **"integrated security=true"**

Comment: No, everything about mdf file is ok.